# How to use Bitcoinj to authenticate signed messages?

Tags: java

I'd like to authenticate from java code on a website that makes use of javascript/ajax authentication like below:

```
var key = new Bitcoin.ECKey(Crypto.util.hexToBytes(SHA256(password)));
var signed_challenge = Crypto.util.bytesToHex(key.sign(Crypto.util.hexToBytes(SHA256(challenge_key))));
```

I found that the library `bitcoinj` offers classes like `ECKey`, but I don't know what I might use as replacement for `CryptoJS` here?

Maybe you could help me translating the JS to Java?

Comment: Maybe reword the question to "How to use Bitcoinj to authenticate signed messages?"